# Lazy observable sequence that replays value or error

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I am trying to create an observable pipeline with the following characteristics:

- is lazy (does nothing until somebody subscribes)
- executes at most once regardless of how many subscriptions are received
- replays its resulting value, if any OR
- replays its resulting error, if any

For the life of me, I can't figure out the correct semantics to accomplish this. I thought it would be a simple case of doing something like this:

```
Observable
    .Defer(() => Observable
        .Start(() => { /* do something */ })
        .PublishLast()
        .ConnectUntilCompleted());
```

Where `ConnectUntilCompleted` just does what it sounds like:

```
public static IObservable<T> ConnectUntilCompleted<T>(this IConnectableObservable<T> @this)
{
    @this.Connect();
    return @this;
}
```

This seems to work when the observable terminates successfully, but not when there's an error. Any subscribers do not receive the error:

```
[Fact]
public void test()
{
    var o = Observable
        .Defer(() => Observable
            .Start(() => { throw new InvalidOperationException(); })
            .PublishLast()
            .ConnectUntilCompleted());

    // this does not throw!
    o.Subscribe();
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Why doesn't `Publish` replay any error it receives?

**UPDATE**: it gets even stranger:

```
[Fact]
public void test()
{
    var o = Observable
        .Defer(() => Observable
            .Start(() => { throw new InvalidOperationException(); })
            .PublishLast()
            .ConnectUntilCompleted())
        .Do(
            _ => { },
            ex => { /* this executes */ });

    // this does not throw!
    o.Subscribe();

    o.Subscribe(
        _ => { },
        ex => { /* even though this executes */ });
}
```

Comment: Your subscriber stops receiving notifications as soon as you discard the results of Subscribe. Try holding onto them for a while.

Comment: You seem to have some issues with the understanding of observables. They are all lazy - even hot ones - and all do nothing until there is a subscriber. Every observable is a **definition**. When you subscribe you get a new pipeline **created** for each subscription. The pipelines are independent of each other (unless you use a publish or a subject to share a portion of the pipeline). Therefore you can't replay errors - once an error occurs the pipeline that's been created shuts down. You can repeat values though as the contract is `OnNext*(OnError|OnCompleted)` - so multiple values, one error.

Comment: Ah, but I think I see what you're trying to do with the `.PublishLast()`. It'll hold the for each future subscription. I think I have some code for you that might help.

Comment: I think there's a race condition going on here. If I run this without the debugger attached multiple times, I can get it to throw after a few tries.

Comment: In fact, you should be able to move the `o.Subscribe` to be the last line, and it should throw.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez is correct. As you are executing your tests in a multi-threaded way (Obs.Start is using a default of the TaskPoolScheduler) your test finishes before the exception is throw. If you drop in a TestScheduler into your tests, you see the exception being thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this version of you `ConnectUntilCompleted` method:

```
public static IObservable<T> ConnectUntilCompleted<T>(this IConnectableObservable<T> @this)
{
    return Observable.Create<T>(o =>
    {
        var subscription = @this.Subscribe(o);
        var connection = @this.Connect();
        return new CompositeDisposable(subscription, connection);
    });
}
```

The allows Rx to behave properly.

Now I've added to it to help show what's going on:

```
public static IObservable<T> ConnectUntilCompleted<T>(this IConnectableObservable<T> @this)
{
    return Observable.Create<T>(o =>
    {
        var disposed = Disposable.Create(() => Console.WriteLine("Disposed!"));
        var subscription = Observable
            .Defer<T>(() => { Console.WriteLine("Subscribing!"); return @this; })
            .Subscribe(o);
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting!");
        var connection = @this.Connect();
        return new CompositeDisposable(disposed, subscription, connection);
    });
}
```

Now your observable looks like this:

```
var o =
    Observable
        .Defer(() =>
            Observable
                .Start(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Started.");
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }))
        .PublishLast()
        .ConnectUntilCompleted();
```

The final key thing is to actually handle the errors in the subscription - so it's not enough to simply do `o.Subscribe()`.

So do this:

```
        o.Subscribe(
            x => Console.WriteLine(x),
            e => Console.WriteLine(e.Message),
            () =>  Console.WriteLine("Done."));

        o.Subscribe(
            x => Console.WriteLine(x),
            e => Console.WriteLine(e.Message),
            () =>  Console.WriteLine("Done."));

        o.Subscribe(
            x => Console.WriteLine(x),
            e => Console.WriteLine(e.Message),
            () =>  Console.WriteLine("Done."));
```

When I run that I get this:

```
Subscribing!
Connecting!
Subscribing!
Connecting!
Subscribing!
Connecting!
Started.
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
Disposed!
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
Disposed!
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
Disposed!
```

Note that "Started" only appears once, but the error is reported three times.

(Sometimes `Started` appears higher up in the list after the first subscription.)

I think this is what you wanted from your description.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply @Enigmativity. Unfortunately, it doesn't quite exhibit the behavior I am after. I think `ConnectUntilCompleted` is a poor name. What I want is for any future subscriber to receive the same result, even if all previous subscribers have disposed of their subscription. Maybe it's actually a bad idea (it certainly feels against the grain) but I'm trying to model an async method call. So the obs represents the result of that method call and any future subscriber should just receive the same result. If a new call is desired, a new obs altogether would be required.

Comment: @KentBoogaart - All future subscribers do receive the same result. If you replace the `throw` with a `return 42` then you'll see that `"Started."` only happens once, but the three subscriptions all get the same value. And that does happen after the previous callers have disposed of their subscriptions.

Comment: I think I'm getting confused by the fact that sometimes a `Subscribe()` will throw immediately (or when I advance scheduler) whereas other times it does not (and would require an explicit error handler to "see" the error).

Comment: @KentBoogaart - `.Subscribe(...)` doesn't throw. The observable pipeline throws. If you have a handler for errors in your subscriber then you get to handle the errors cleanly. If not then the pipeline should throw. As per usual you should write code that doesn't throw unless there is no way to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

Just to support @Engimativity's answer, i want to show how you should be runing your tests so you stop getting these "surprises". Your tests are non-deterministic because they are multi-threaded/concurrent. Your use of `Observable.Start` without providing an `IScheduler` is problematic. If you run your tests with a `TestScheduler` your tests will now be singlethreaded and determinisitic

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
    var o = Observable
        .Defer(() => Observable
            .Start(() => { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }, testScheduler)
            .PublishLast()
            .ConnectUntilCompleted());

    var observer = testScheduler.CreateObserver<Unit>();
    o.Subscribe(observer);

    testScheduler.Start();

    CollectionAssert.IsNotEmpty(observer.Messages);
    Assert.AreEqual(NotificationKind.OnError, observer.Messages[0].Value.Kind);
}
```

Comment: I completely forgot that `Start` isn't using `ImmediateScheduler` by default. I really need to write those Roslyn analyzers to warn whenever you call a method that takes a scheduler and you don't provide one. Thanks Lee. That said, the goal of the observable I'm trying to construct is that it shouldn't _matter_ if it's already completed - you should get the value (or error) when you subscribe.

Comment: Yes, that would be true for the subsequent subscribers (if the original subscription had made the sequence error before that time)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to achieve your requirements could be:

```
var lazy = new Lazy<Task>(async () => { /* execute once */ }, isThreadSafe: true);
var o = Observable.FromAsync(() => lazy.Value);
```

When subscribed for the first time, `lazy` would create (and execute) the task. For other subscriptions, `lazy` would return the same (possibly already completed or failed) task.